How to make a prompt to open different things with a batch file in DOSBox?
I've been making batch file shortcuts to my dos games in dosbox, and I want to make a batch file for doom 2 that asks you if you want to open doom 2, or open the setup file by typing either 1 or 2. How would I do that?
I tried asking ChatGPT for the batch file code to do that (See below), but it just opens doom 2 regardless of input. I have barely any experience in batch file coding, so I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.
@echo off
echo Select a file to open:
echo 1. DOOM2.EXE
echo 2. SETUP.EXE

set /p choice=Enter your choice (1-2): 
pause

if "%choice%"=="1" (
    DOOM2.bat
) else if "%choice%"=="2" (
    SETDOM2.bat
pause
) else (
    echo Invalid choice. Exiting...
    pause
    exit /b
)


I commend to your attention ss64 on CHOICE.

We are not here to fix code provided by ChatGPT, either.

What is in the other two .bat files?

@phuclv seems OP is actually using DosBox, which uses its own shell.

Display a menu with echo and wait for the user's response via the choice command that sets the errorlevel. It is important that these errorlevels get interrogated from high to low:
@echo off
echo Make selection (press # and ENTER)
echo ==================================
echo 1. DOOM2.EXE
echo 2. SETUP.EXE
echo 3. EXIT MENU
choice /c123
if errorlevel 3 goto exit
if errorlevel 2 goto setup
if errorlevel 1 goto play

:play
call DOOM2.bat
goto exit

:setup
call SETDOM2.bat

:exit
echo .

This was tested in DOSBox 0.74 just now.
